# How to get all URL's from page?

Tags: jquery

I try to get all URL's fro this page (http://www.fotocommunity.de/fotograf/tu-fotodesign/fotos/794400) with jquery.

When you scroll, the site will add pix with AJAX. Here a snip of my script:

```
for (i=0; i<100; i++) 
{
    var zahl=$('#thumbnails LI').eq(i).attr('id');
    var time=$('#thumbnails LI').eq(i).attr('data-time');
    console.log(i + ': ' + zahl+ ' ' + time);
}
```

I always get only the first 12 Items. Any ideas, how to get all?
I tried also `mouseover` or click events, but always it works only with the first 12 elements.

Comment: Where are you putting this code? How do you run it?

Comment: You can't what it is not already there. Also, I'm a bit afraid of where this question is going

Comment: i do it with greasemonkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or if you want to do it the super fun way!

```
var previous_scroll_top = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  $("body").scrollTop(3000000);

  // Don't do anything until we reach the bottom of the page!
  if (previous_scroll_top != $("body").scrollTop()) {
    previous_scroll_top = $("body").scrollTop();
    return true;
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }

  // Once we reach the bottom do this :)
  $('#thumbnails LI').each(function(index, el) {
    var zahl=$(el).attr('id');
    var time=$(el).attr('data-time');
    console.log(': ' + zahl+ ' ' + time);
  });
},1000);
```

Comment: great! it will return more than 12 elements. Thanks!

Comment: >.< Wow. All the URLs are in the XML file.

Comment: @bobthyasian yes, but this way is far more amusing/insane ;)

Answer (score 3):

The website you supplied uses an 'endless' scroll effect. The images are populated from an XML file. 
 [Found here](http://www.fotocommunity.de/rss/feed/params/Y2hhbm5lbD0yJmdlbmJ5PTEyMTM5NjcmZmNsYW5nPTEmdGl0ZWw9RGllK25ldWVzdGVuK0JpbGRlcithdXMrZGVtK0NoYW5uZWwrR2FsZXJpZQ.xml)

All you needed to do is read the source to find this out.

Comment: **+1** You can read the source with [**YQL**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) data scraping technique. Press the [**TREE Button**](http://y.ahoo.it/U0rfB) to see **50** items.

Comment: I just used Chrome's Inspector, read the javascript and made a deduction. You know, the old fashion way.

Comment: @arttronics On a personal level, data scrapping feels invasive. Dunno why I feel that way.

Comment: @bobthyasian, think of it this way: Data scraping a RSS feed for select data returns less data than requesting the whole XML file. That saves on bandwidth, which in turn saves on energy which reduces global warming, thus making data scraping a Green thing to do, just sayin.

Comment: @arttronics I totally agree. My only issue is that computers do as they are told and don't think. Sometimes they miss what a human would have seen.

Answer (score 2):

jquery each() is a better option than a for loop

This jquery snippet will get all the hrefs from a page

```
var hrefs = $(document).find('a').map(function(){
    return this.href;
}).toArray();
```

You need to apply some logic to get just the photo hrefs, but this should get you started

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery's each for looping through elements: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: $('#thumbnails LI').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});   ---> 12 Elements